# myWebview.setDownloadListener is not working

Tags: android

I am trying to download an excel file from a sharepoint site, using webview.setdownloadlister in my android app programming.
And the file is not getting downloaded.

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        String title = URLUtil.guessFileName(String.valueOf(url), contentDisposition, mimetype);
        request.setTitle(title);
        request.setDescription("Downloading File please wait");
        String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        if (cookie != null) {
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookie);
        }
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request. setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(),Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/Download/", title);
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        registerReceiver(onComplete,new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }
    
    BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Downloading is complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    };
});
```

Comment: Recommendation: when you post a question, format the code to make things easier on individuals viewing your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more on this.